# Persisting Authentication Across keep-alive Connection

Tags: php, apache, http, authentication, keep-alive

Currently on my website when a user is logged in, for every webpage request you have to go to the database and check their cookie to confirm who they are, doing this across keep-alive connections is a waste because that connection was already authenticated, how can I, using PHP and/or apache, persist authentication across a keep-alive connection? Is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 1):

just check the cookie to enter the site with a connection to the database,

If the checking is ok: you create a session cookie with a unique encryption 
exemple

```
md5("NAME"."PASS".Time()))
```

you are using an SQL only once per session ;)